# Remove intersect line for one circle using venndiagram2sets

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, line, venn-diagrams

**Problem:**

I wish to remove the intersecting line for circle A (left).

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{venndiagram2sets}[radius=1.3cm,labelA=,labelB=]
            \fillOnlyA
            \setpostvennhook
            {
                \draw (labelA) node[below=6ex] {A\textbackslash B};
                \draw (labelB) node[below=6ex] {B};
            }
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
        \caption{$\mathbf{A}$\textbackslash$\mathbf{B}$}
        \label{fig:venncup}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

To remove the right line for the left circle - alternatively fill circle B (right) with white color to cover the line.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Are you open in "just `tikz`" solutioons? I think you will find much easier an answer and it will be simple

Comment: @koleygr Yes I am

Comment: Perhaps you could add a white arc to circle A?

Comment: @Bernard How would I do that using the `venndiagram` package?

Comment: You'd probably have to insert some pure TikZ code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `venndiagram` package is very well written and hence easy to customize. I added a style `interior B` (and also `interior A`) that can be used as follows:

```
\fill[white,interior B];
```

This fills the right circle white. One could add several other similar styles, if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{showframe}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{interior A/.style={insert path={
 (\@venn@Ax,\@venn@Ay) circle[radius=\@venn@radius-\pgflinewidth/2]}},
 interior B/.style={insert path={
 (\@venn@Bx,\@venn@By) circle[radius=\@venn@radius-\pgflinewidth/2]}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{venndiagram2sets}[radius=1.3cm,labelA=,labelB=]
            \fillOnlyA
            \setpostvennhook
            {
                \fill[white,interior B];
                \draw (labelA) node[below=6ex] {A\textbackslash B};
                \draw (labelB) node[below=6ex] {B};
            }
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
        \caption{$\mathbf{A}$\textbackslash$\mathbf{B}$}
        \label{fig:venncup}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in my opinion, customizing the "venndiagram" package is boring! at least "plain" TikZ is much easier to customizing

Answer (score 8):

A solution with "plain `tikz`":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
                \draw (-4,-3)rectangle (6,3);
                \fill[gray,draw=black] (0,0)  circle (2cm); 
                \node at (0,0){A\textbackslash B};
                \fill[white,draw=black] (3cm,0) circle  (2cm);
                \node at (3cm,0) {B};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\mathbf{A}$\textbackslash$\mathbf{B}$}
        \label{fig:venncup}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a bit simpler \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=gray!50] (0,0) circle(1) node{$A{\setminus}B$};
\draw[fill=white] (1.5,0) circle(1) node{$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: @BlackMild Yes ... it is ... You just lost the rectangle. use the latex open quote of your keyboard to place (inline) code in your comments and answers like: `test` (inside "LaTeX opening quotes")